# How to synchronized runnables to start one after another?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

In my android app I'm trying to show a sequence of button presses (one after another) to remember and to repeat by user. To do this I'm using runnables with postDelay methods to change UI. Currently all buttons in sequence are showing at the same moment and all are hiding at the same moment. Could somebody help me to synchronize runnables to show one after another not together? Code is given below.

```
for(int i = 0; i < generatedSequenceToPlay.size(); i++){
        final int position = i;
        _handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public synchronized void run() {
                findButtonById(_defuseButtonHandler.getKeyByValue(generatedSequenceToPlay.get(position).toString())).setPressed(true);
            }
        }, 500);
        _handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public synchronized void run() {
                findButtonById(_defuseButtonHandler.getKeyByValue(generatedSequenceToPlay.get(position).toString())).setPressed(false);

            }
        }, 500);
    }
```

Comment: increase `postDelayed` last parameter for each loop iteration, for example: `500 * (i+1)`

Comment: have synchronization on some common object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the method explanation of `postDelayed` on [this page.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable,%20long))

> Causes the Runnable r to be added to the message queue, to be run
>   after the specified amount of time elapses. The runnable will be run
>   on the thread to which this handler is attached.

When the specified time elapses, the runnable task will be got from message queue and attached to thread for running. All runnable tasks will be run **almost** at the same time after 500 milliseconds since each task isn't time-consuming. So as @pskink suggested, give each runnable task a different timer will do you the favour.

For example, you can modify code like below.

```
for(int i = 0; i < generatedSequenceToPlay.size(); i++){
        final int position = i;
        _handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public synchronized void run() {
                findButtonById(_defuseButtonHandler.getKeyByValue(generatedSequenceToPlay.get(position).toString())).setPressed(true);
            }
        }, 500 + i * 100);
        _handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public synchronized void run() {
                findButtonById(_defuseButtonHandler.getKeyByValue(generatedSequenceToPlay.get(position).toString())).setPressed(false);

            }
        }, 500 + i * 100);
    }
```